# KMeans clustering with labels data

Tags: scikit-learn, k-means, image-segmentation, unsupervised-learning, semantic-segmentation

I have a RGB image of shape (587, 987, 3). #height, width, num_channels

I also have label data (pixels' locations) for each of 7 classes.

I wanted to apply KMeans clustering algorithm to segment the given image into 7 classes.
While applying KMeans clustering, I want to utilize the label data, i.e., pixels locations.

How can I utilize label data?

What I have tried so far is as follows.

```
img = np.random.randint(low=1,high=99, size=(587, 987, 3)) 

im = img.reshape(img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], img.shape[2])
im = StandardScaler().fit_transform(im)

clusters = KMeans(n_clusters=7,n_init= 100,max_iter=100,n_jobs=-1).fit(im)
kmeans_labels = clusters.labels_.reshape(img.shape[0], img.shape[1])

plt.imshow(kmeans_labels)
plt.show()
```

I'm looking for propagating some annotation to the remaining segments (superpixels)

Comment: What you are looking for is a semi-supervised learning method. In the context of image segmentation, they are related to interactive segmentation techniques. It would be beneficial if you could provide more details about your problem and what you have tried because some assumptions will boost the performance of your algorithm.

Comment: I have updated the question to show what I have tried so far. I could not figure out how can I utilize labels in the context of semi-supervised learning.

Comment: Ok, but what is your final goal? Is your problem only to assign labels to the k-means clusters? One possibility would be just to assign each cluster the label that appears the most in it, it is not the best approach because it is not a classification algorithm but it answers your question. However, I think you are looking for propagating some annotation to the remaining segments (superpixels?) in an image if this is the case you could elaborate more on your problem.

Comment: This might be an XY problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: yes, exactly. I'm looking for propagating some annotation to the remaining segments (superpixels)

Comment: "You will provide a minimal code for ..."- please note that this kind of language might be a turn off for a lot of people

Comment: I think the content of the question could be revised from what we discussed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As clarified in the comments of the question, you could treat the cluster as superpixels and propagate labels from a few samples to the remaining data, using some semi-supervised classifier [1].

Creating an image to run the example:

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage.data import binary_blobs
import cv2 
from pyift.shortestpath import seed_competition
from scipy import sparse, spatial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# creating noisy image
size = 256 
image = np.empty((size, size, 3)) 
image[:, :, 0] = binary_blobs(size, seed=0)
image[:, :, 1] = binary_blobs(size, seed=0)
image[:, :, 2] = binary_blobs(size, seed=1)
image += np.random.randn(*image.shape) / 10
image -= image.min()
image /= image.max()

plt.axis(False)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

[image: noisy image]

Computing superpixels:

```py
def grid_seeds(image, rows = 15, cols = 15):
    seeds = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=np.int)
    v_step, h_step = image.shape[0] // rows, image.shape[1] // cols
    count = 1
    for i in range(rows):
        y = v_step // 2 + i * v_step
        for j in range(cols):
            x = h_step // 2 + j * h_step
            seeds[y, x] = count
            count += 1
    return seeds
                                                                                                 
seeds = grid_seeds(image)
_, _, _, superpixels = seed_competition(seeds, image=image)
superpixels -= 1  # shifting labels to zero

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(superpixels, cv2.RETR_FLOODFILL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
im_w_contours = image.copy()
cv2.drawContours(im_w_contours, contours, -1, (255, 0, 0))

plt.axis(False)
plt.imshow(im_w_contours)
plt.show()
```

[image: superpixels]

Propagating labels from 4 arbitrary nodes, one for each class (color) and coloring the resulting labels with the expected color.

```py
def create_graph(image, labels):
    n_nodes = labels.max() + 1
    h, w, d = image.shape
    avg = np.zeros((n_nodes, d))
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            avg[labels[i, j]] += image[i, j]
    avg[:] /= np.bincount(labels.flat)[:, np.newaxis]  # ignore label 0
    graph = spatial.distance_matrix(avg, avg)
    return sparse.csr_matrix(graph)

graph = create_graph(image, superpixels)

graph_seeds = np.zeros(graph.shape[0], dtype=np.int)
graph_seeds[1] = 1   # blue training sample
graph_seeds[3] = 2   # yellow training sample
graph_seeds[13] = 3  # white training sample
graph_seeds[14] = 4  # black training sample

label_colors = {1: (0, 0, 255),
                2: (255, 255, 0),
                3: (255, 255, 255),
                4: (0, 0, 0)}

_, _, _, labels = seed_competition(graph_seeds, graph=graph)

result = np.empty_like(image)
for i, lb in enumerate(labels):
    result[superpixels == i] = label_colors[lb]

plt.axis(False)
plt.imshow(result)
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

For this example, I used the difference between the average color of each superpixel as their arc-weight. However, in a real problem, some more elaborate feature vector will be necessary.

Also, the labeled data is a subset of the image superpixels, but this is not strictly necessary, you can add any artificial node when modeling your graph, especially as the seed nodes.

This approach is commonly used in remote sensing, this article might be relevant [2].

[1] Amorim, W. P., Falcão, A. X., Papa, J. P., & Carvalho, M. H. (2016). Improving semi-supervised learning through optimum connectivity. Pattern Recognition, 60, 72-85.

[2] Vargas, John E., et al. "Superpixel-based interactive classification of very high resolution images." 2014 27th SIBGRAPI Conference on Graphics, Patterns, and Images. IEEE, 2014.